# Why can't we forward declare classes/structs with known size in C++?

Tags: c++

there is the problem in C++ that parts of the implementation, namely inline functions and private member variables, leak into the header file. Inline functions are not neccessary any more when using LTO (except for constexpr functions). There are workarounds for private variables in the header, e.g. the Pimpl idiom, but they have their drawbacks, i.e. cumbersome to use and/or less than ideal performance. In my mind there currently exists an easy solution for this problem: allowing forward declaration of classes/structs and manually specifying their size. We already have this concept in C++ for enumerations. The enumeration can be used, e.g. as a member of a struct before the named values are known:

```
enum E : int;

struct S
{
    E e;
    float foo;
};
```

If we now extend this concept to forward declarations of classes/structs we could do the following (I'm borrowing the syntax for bit fields to specify the size for now):

```
// header s.h

// forward declare SVariables and tell the compiler it is 16 bytes in size
struct SVariables : 16; 

class S : private SVariables
{
public:
    void foo();
};

// implementation s.cpp

struct SVariables
{
    float x, y, z, w;
};

void S::foo()
{
    x = 1.0f;
}
```

It would be the programmers responsibility to specify the correct or a large enough size in the forward declaration (which is also the case with enumerations). However, mistakes would immediately lead to a compiler error in the implementation file when the class/struct is fully defined and the previously specified size doesn't match or is too small.

(The compiler would probably not be able to auto generate special member functions, e.g. constructor, destructor, copy-constructor, etc., if the forward declared class/struct is not trivial.)

The answer to the headline question is of course: because the standard doesn't allow it. So I would like to ask the following questions:

- What are the problems I am currently not seeing?
- Has this ever been considered?
- If no, would it be worth proposing it?

(I couldn't really find anything like the above concept on the www, so please excuse me if this has already be discussed somewhere.)

Thank you,
jffmichi

Comment: how would the compiler issue an error for the wrong size when it doesnt have the definition?

Comment: `enum` is really easy to forward declare.  It's just a new type defined on top of an existing one.  How can you know that it will be `100` bits wide?  Compilers are allowed to add padding, so it's hard to guarantee a class's size.

Comment: `struct alignas(16) SVariables{};` ? You'd have to inherit it in the `SVariables` implementation though.

Comment: This is one of "why is this not in the standard" questions. The correct answer is usually "because it is not there".

Comment: The error would be issued in the implementation file where both the forward declared size and the actual definition are known.

Comment: What if they are in two different translation units?  For example Foo.h has `struct bar : 16;` and then Bar.cpp implements `bar` and Foo.cpp only implements `foo`.

Comment: @NathanOliver that would be the exact purpose of the proposal. Foo.cpp would compile just fine because it knows the size of `bar` but it would of course not be able to use member variables in `bar`.

Comment: @jffmichi But what if you're wrong?  Lets say someone messes up in Bar.cpp and `bar` become 20 bytes instead of 16.  What happens then?  `bar` and `foo` are compiled separately, so you can't cross check.

Comment: @NathanOliver Foo.cpp would still compile but Bar.cpp would not. To fix it the programmer would need to change either Bar.cpp (shrinking the definition of `bar` to 16 bytes) and recompile it or change Foo.h (specifing 20 bytes for `bar`) which would cause a recompilation of both Foo.cpp and Bar.cpp.

Comment: So it's a link-time error?

Comment: @Caleth no, it's a compile-time error in Bar.cpp

Comment: when `Bar.cpp` and `Foo.cpp` are compiled seperately the discrepancy can only be detected when linking, unless I miss something fundamental (actually that was the whole point of my first comment, should have been more clear)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 but you can't compile Bar.cpp with a different size than the one that was specified in Foo.h because that would give a compiler error (assuming of course Foo.h is included in Bar.cpp, but if it's not the two are completely separated which is already a problem with current C++). Unless I'm missing something :)

Comment: IMHO the hard part would be for a programmer to guess what will be the actual size. A number of types have implementation dependant sizes, even in common and current compilers. Specifically, pointers are 4 or 8 bytes long. And every virtual function adds en entry in the vtable (I know it is an implementation detail but any size question is...). Furthermore, you are hitting a fundamental point of the language, inherited from C, the notion of *complete* type. You proposal would add a new concept of *partially complete* type. As this is deep in the language I cannot even imagine the consequences.

Comment: @NathanOliver: lying to compiler would be ill formed, as if you forward declare `enum class E : char` and implement it as `int` in another TU.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, the more I think about it could just be made ill-formed; NDR.  The idea is interesting, just not sure if we can or even should added since it's "hard" to actually know what the size of an object will be, at least in a generic sense.

Comment: @NathanOliver: I would be more interested by a way to forward declare classes with (partial) inheritance than size.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because this is reasonably easy to accomplish in library, but such a facility is not in widespread use, demonstrating lack of demand. For example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>
#include <utility>
template<std::size_t Size, std::size_t Align, class T>
struct fwd {
    alignas(Align) std::byte buf[Size];
    template<class... Args> requires (sizeof(T) <= Size && alignof(T) <= Align &&
        !std::is_same_v<fwd(std::remove_cvref_t<Args>...), fwd(fwd)>)
    fwd(Args&&... args) { new (buf) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
    fwd(fwd&& rhs) : fwd(std::move(rhs.get())) {}
    fwd(fwd const& rhs) : fwd(rhs.get()) {}
    fwd& operator=(fwd&& rhs) { get() = std::move(rhs.get()); return *this; }
    fwd& operator=(fwd const& rhs) { get() = rhs.get(); return *this; }
    ~fwd() { get().~T(); }
    T& get() { return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(buf)); }
    T const& get() const { return *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T const*>(buf)); }
};
```

[Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s74P6K).

Realistically, if you're paying the optimization hit of a compiler barrier, which LTO doesn't entirely obviate, then the additional cost of a free store allocation isn't going to be particularly visible and comes with the significant advantage of never having to change size or alignment (yes, even if you plan ahead).

Comment: `fwd(Arg&&...)` catches `fwd(fwd&)`.

Comment: There is [std::aligned_storage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) for `buf`.

Comment: @Jarod42 fixed, thanks, those rogue copy constructors are always a pain. Don't see the point of `std::aligned_storage` myself.

Comment: You use equivalent code of `std::aligned_storage` for `buf`. It was not an error, just an "improvement" of type meaning :-)

Comment: I didn't have this on the radar. Concerning Pimpl: it's not only (de-)allocation but also the additional pointer indirection that I deem negative in some cases. Your code avoids both. Obviously this is not something you would use on every single class but I think there are some cases where I will adapt your solution. Thank you very much!